# proving theorems about quadratic function

Tags: quadratics

The theorems I want to prove are:

$$\text {if } a + b + c = 0 \text{ then } x_1 = 1 \text { and } x_2= c/a$$
 $$   \text{if } a - b + c = 0 \text{ then } x_1 = - 1 \text{ and } x_2 = -c/a $$

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of the equation and $a,b$ and $c$ are the parameters. In my textbook the only thing which is said is that this is easily proven by Viet's formulas. However I can see how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

If $a+b+c=0$ this implies $P(1)=0$. This implies that $1$ is a root of $P(x)$. Note that the multiple of the two roots of a quadratic is $\frac{a}{c}$. However, one root is $1$. Thus, the other remaining solution is  $\frac{a}{c}$.

In the same method, $a-b+c=0$ implies $P(-1)=0$, and so $-\frac{a}{c}$ is a solution.

In general, if $ak^2+bk+c=0$, one solution is $k$ and the other is $\frac{a}{ck}$, which one can prove using the method above.

Comment: Thank you, I will mark it as best answer when I can.